# Which infinitive to use with "sein"?

Tags: english-to-german, infinitive

I've looked around a bit and I haven't been able to figure this out:

I often say things in English like, "I am excited to eat lunch"

I'm not sure which form of the infinitive to use. Would it be:

> *Ich bin aufgeregt Mittagessen essen*.

or

> *Ich bin aufgeregt Mittagessen **zu** essen*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that "excited" here is used as "enthusiasticly looking forward to" and not as "nervous and jittery", perhaps translatig it as "sich auf etwas freuen" might be the better choice of words:

> Ich freue mich auf das Mittagessen.

Or, when sitting at the table, grateful for the meal:

> Ich freue mich über das Mittagessen.

And - as you asked in the question - with infinitive + zu:

> Ich freue mich [darauf], Mittag zu essen.

Comment: I wonder why you add the second "zu" and add the hint although you could drop it completely for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I agree with Em1: »Ich freue mich [darauf], Mittag zu essen.« is an absolute correct German sentence. Here »Mittag zu essen« is used in the same way as »Rad zu fahren«.

Answer (score 0):

To say `i am excited to eat lunch` it is :

> Ich bin davon begeistert, zu Mittag zu essen.

Or you can also say it like this:

> Ich bin von dem Mittagessen begeistert.

Or

> Ich bin vom Mittagessen begeistert.

Comment: Your second (and third sentence respectively) have a completely different meaning than the first one.

Comment: How different? I thought they all meant the same.